# Where can I get data on the location both the investors and the assignees?

Tags: databases

I am a researcher wanting to examine how companies assign patents for tax planning purposes.  As I search databases like Google Patents, I see a ton of data, and the PDF of the patent itself.  However, it does not appear that Google captures the location of the inventor(s) or the assignee of the patent. This is also not in the NBER patent data.

Does anyone know a database where I can get data on both the name of the assignee, as well as the location of the assignee, and the location of the inventors (preferably in one large dataset that could be downloaded all at once)?

Answer (score 1):

For assignee information the USPTO has that data in XML form. To relieve their servers they have a deal with Reed Tech. to host the data, unchanged and for free. Look at http://patents.reedtech.com/assignment.php

Answer (score 1):

http://www.patentsview.org/ is probably what you are looking for.  IT has this data available as a large download or as an API service.  It's always a little bit out of data but should work for some use cases.